# Mixing max-width limited element with one that uses percentage

Tags: css

https://jsfiddle.net/eh9h6etw/

When one of the two columns in a main wrapper is limited by a max-width, irrespective if it also has a percentage value (say 30%), upon resizing (making window larger), the second column (70%) of course does not run until the edge of the main wrapper when it's stretched out enough and second column 70% plus the fixed 150px layer are not enough to run edge to edge, how can I make it run until the end ? I want the 'blue' coloured div to run all the way to the other end without showing the yellow gap.

```css
.main 
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.rowholder
{
    background-color: cyan;
    float: left;
    width:70%;
}

.image
{
    background-color: orange;
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
    width: 30%;
}

.row
{
    background-color: blue;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="image"></div>
    
    <div class="rowholder">
    <div class="row">This should span until the other edge</div>
    <div class="row">This should span until the other edge</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When one of the two columns in a main wrapper is limited by a
>   max-width, irrespective if it also has a percentage value (say 30%),
>   upon resizing (making window larger), the second column (70%) of
>   course does not run until the edge

That is because of `max-width` on your left column. When it reaches `150px` it does not expand further, and `150px` gets smaller than the `30%` you specified. That will leave the difference on the right-column because that is constrained only to `70%`.

To fix this, you have to specify a `min-width` on the second-column as well as calculate a width which is a difference of `100%` minus `150px` (*of the left one*).

Like this:

```
.rowholder {
    ...
    min-width: 70%;
    width: calc(100% - 150px);
}
```

**Your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/eh9h6etw/17/**

**Snippet:**

```css
.main { float: left; width: 100%; background-color: yellow; }
.rowholder {
    background-color: cyan; float: left;
    min-width: 70%;
    width: calc(100% - 150px);
}
.image {
    background-color: orange; float: left; height: 150px;
    max-width: 150px; width: 30%;
}
.row { background-color: blue; clear: both; float: left; width: 100%; }
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="rowholder">
        <div class="row">Helow this is the heading</div>
        <div class="row"> this is the second row</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand the math and what was wrong. Just didn't know the calc() function even existed. Seems I am little outdated and stuck in CSS2 land.

Comment: Would I also be correct in presuming there's no ready class in bootstrap that would let me attain this exact result ?

Comment: @LaserBeak: No not really. But you could take a look at CSS flexbox model. It is very flexible and allow you to get this thing done without calcs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `max-width:150px;` because you are setting higher value to `width` , than to `max-width`... max-width which is 150px and `width:30%` which is more than 150px.So your code should look like this

```
.rowholder
{
    background-color: cyan;
    float: left;
    width:85%;
}
```

and

```
.image
{
    background-color: orange;
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    width:15%;
}
```

After that , if you'r going to apply some image , you have to adjust your percentages in depends on the image's height and width.

Comment: Any percentage with can be more or less than 150px, depending on viewport size, so that wouldn't help. At 15% the image is too narrow anywhere.